# How to give internet connection to flutter web pages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Pages in `flutter` web keeps on loading but noting renders ,

do not respond  to api calls as well, seems having internet connection issue .
i have tried A lot of issue how to resolve it?
finally found an exception as

`flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Bad state: StreamSink is closed`

Comment: please post the code where you see the error. ` "Bad state: StreamSink is closed` suggests you have closed the StreamController ahead of listening or adding data to it.

Answer (score -1):

If it's due to the internet issue..Make sure to include below line in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: OP mentions about flutter web, where `AndroidManifest.xml` is not in use.So this might not help in this case.